# sort a list of integers by rank in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function that for each number, it counts how many
elements are smaller than it (this is the number’s rank) and then places the number in its rank in the sorted list. Say I have a list

```
L=(4,7,9,10,6,11,3)
```

What I want to produce is a corresponding list

```
K=(1,3,4,5,2,6,0)
```

where element K[i] has the value of the 'rank' of the element for the corresponding location in L. I wrote this code:

```
def sort_by_rank(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        # rank = how many elements are smaller than lst[i]?
        rank = 0
        for elem in lst:
            if elem < lst[i]:
                rank += 1
        lst[rank] = lst[i]
    return lst
```

but it has a bug that i don't manage to debug.

Comment: you need to specify what if elements can be the same, duplicate elements can mess with the result

Answer (score 3):

The simpler way to do this is make a sorted copy of the list, then get the indexes:

```
L = [4,7,9,10,6,11,3]
s = sorted(L)
result = [s.index(x) for x in L]  # [1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 6, 0]
```

Now, this is the naive approach, and it works great for small lists like yours, but for long lists it would be slow since `list.index` is relatively slow and it's being run over and over.

To make it more efficient, use `enumerate` to make a dict of element-index pairs. Lookups in a dict are much faster than `list.index`.

```
s = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(sorted(set(L)))}
result = [s[x] for x in L]  # [1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 6, 0]
```

Here I'm also converting `L` to a set in case of duplicates, otherwise later occurrences would override the indexes of earlier ones.

Comment: Note that the use of the `list.index` method unnecessarily makes this solution of *O(n ^ 2)* in time complexity. It also won't support any duplicates in the list.

Comment: @blhsing Excellent point. I've added a faster option using a dict.

Comment: @blhsing I'm not sure what you mean. OP's algorithm treats duplicates as the same, and mine does too, no?

Comment: @blhsing Like if the input is `[4, 5, 4]`, the output will be `[0, 1, 0]`

Comment: Never mind. I had a different interpretation of how duplicates are resolved but upon rereading the OP's code I think your interpretation is indeed closer to the intention demonstrated by the OP's code.

Comment: @blhsing Were you thinking duplicates are counted separately, like `[4, 5, 4]` -> `[0, 2, 1]`? That would make intuitive sense, but actually I just ran a variation of OP's code and it returned `[0, 2, 0]`, which makes more sense now that I think about it logcially. hmm...

Comment: Yes that was my interpretation, but since in the OP's code the rank only increases by one when the current value differs from the last (the OP is really just missing a call to `sorted` first), I think your output of `[0, 1, 0]` is closer to the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `L` and `K` are not lists, they are tuples. Your code probably bugged because you're trying to modify values within a tuple.

You can use `map` function to map each element to the amount of numbers smaller than it.

```
result = list(map(lambda item: sum([number < item for number in L]), L))
```

know that when calculating sum of `True` and `False`, `True` is same as 1 and `False` is same as 0. By calculating the sum of the new list, where each element is `True`/`False` depending on if item is larger than number, we are essentially counting how many `True` is in the list, which should be what you're asking.

---

My apology, did not saw the part you need you number sorted by the rank. You can use the `key` argument to sort it

```
L = [(item, sum([number < item for number in L])) for item in L]
L.sort(key=lambda item: item[1])
```

where each element in `L` is converted to tuple of (original_value, its_rank)

Comment: `list(map(lambda` ... gross. Use a list comprehension instead: `[sum(n < m for n in L) for m in L]`. Also `sum` can take a generator instead of a list.

Answer (score 0):

For a more efficient approach, you can use `enumerate` to create indices for the items for sorting together, and then use another `enumerate` create indices for the sorted sequence to map the old indices to the sorted indices as a dict, and then iterate an index through the range of the list to output the new indices in a list comprehension:

```
L=(4,7,9,10,6,11,3)
d = {o: i for i, (o, _) in enumerate(sorted(enumerate(L), key=lambda t: t[1]))}
print([d[i] for i in range(len(L))])
```

This outputs:

```
[1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 6, 0]
```